# Product of subspace and its inverse

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, finite-fields, primitive-elements

$\DeclareMathOperator\GF{GF}$Let $R=\GF(q)$ be a finite field with $q=p^r$ elements, where $p$ is a prime number, $S=\GF(q^n)$ be an extension of $R$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 2$ and let $K=\GF(q^{mn})$ be an extension of $S$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $m\geq 2$. That is we have a tower of fields
$$
R<S<K.
$$
For arbitrary nonzero subspace ${}_RW$ of the space ${}_RK$ define
$$
W^{-1}:= \{w^{-1} \ \mid \ w\in W\setminus \{0\}\}
$$
and
$$
W\cdot W^{-1}:= \left\{w\cdot v \ \mid \  w\in W, v\in W^{-1} \right\},
$$
where $\cdot$ is the multiplication operation in $K$.
Finally let $\theta$ be a primitive element of $K$, that is $\operatorname{ord}\theta = |K|-1 = q^{mn} - 1$, and let
$$
H = \left\{\theta^k \;\middle\vert\; k\in \left\{1,2,\ldots, \frac{q^{mn}-1}{q-1}\right\}\right\}.
$$
**My question.** Does there exist a subspace $_RW<{}_RK$ of dimension $n$ such that
$$
H\cap \left(W\cdot W^{-1}\right) = \varnothing?
$$

My experiments have shown that the answer is negative. But I can not prove this. I would be grateful for any ideas and guidance.

Comment: Dimension over what field?

Comment: @WlodAA, dimension over $R$.

Answer (score 0):

The element $\theta^{\frac{q^{mn-1}}{q-1}}$ has order $q-1$, therefore it lies in $R^\times$, the unique subgroup of order $q-1$ of the cyclic group $K^\times$. Now every $r \in R$ can be written as $(rw) \cdot w^{-1} \in W 
\cdot W^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, but $R\cap H = \varnothing$.

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa The argument I gave in the answer should have shown that, with the biggest $k$ as given by the construction of $H$, $\theta^k$ must lie in $R$. Could you please elaborate a bit on how you deduced that $R \cap H = \emptyset$, or maybe point out how the above argument fails?